# What does the -M mean in git branch -M main?

Tags: git

GitHub says to enter `git branch -M main` as a step for creating a new repository on the command line. What does the `-M` mean?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

-M is a flag (shortcut) for `--move --force` per the [docs page on `git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--M). It forcefully renames the branch from `master` (the default branch name for repositories created using the command line is `master`, while those created in GitHub [starting in Oct. 2020] have a default name of `main`) to `main`.

It allows the renaming of the branch even if the new branch name already exists.

Answer (score 15):

git branch -M main

-M automatically renames the master branch to main.