When creating a new depository what's the real purpose of -M in git branch -M main?
I'm creating a new depository and I have to comment exactly all these code lines :
"""
echo "# fleurs" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:johndoe/depo.git
git push -u origin main
"""
Other topics talked about that, but that's not clear. Some say it's for renaming the branch master in main but when you create an empty repository and search for an existing branch nothing appears. So why "git branch main" coudn't just be sufficient ??
Looking at other topics but didn't find a suitable answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68277662/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22branch+-M%22

git branch -M renames the current branch. And it's "repository" with an R, not "depository".

what's the name of the current branch and why this branch did not appear when I run git branch -r ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-do-i-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+current+branch

git branch -r  shows only remote-tracking branches.
